# Confirm edit for Mediawiki 1.34

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I am trying to use ConfirmEdit with Recaptacha but i get an error at the top of the page when i enable it, do anyone know why? i have the latest version of the extension and i am running Mediawiki 1.34. the error goes away when i dissable the extension.

**ERROR**:

Deprecated: Use of Using $ceAllowConfirmedEmail is deprecated, please migrate to $wgAllowConfirmedEmail as a replacement. is deprecated. [Called from require_once in /includes/Setup.php at line 906] in /includes/debug/MWDebug.php on line 333

**LOCAL SETTINGS FILE**

## Recaptacha

wfLoadExtensions([ 'ConfirmEdit', 'ConfirmEdit/ReCaptchaNoCaptcha' ]);

$wgCaptchaClass = 'ReCaptchaNoCaptcha';

$wgReCaptchaSiteKey = '';

$wgReCaptchaSecretKey = '';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you have set `$ceAllowConfirmedEmail` somewhere in your LocalSettings.php. You should replace that variable with `$wgAllowConfirmedEmail`.